# Format datetime timezone

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime object. I want to return a String formatted as this one below:

> Thu, 06 June 2010 16:00:00 +0200

This is my code so far:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

Result:

> Thu, 10 Juni 2010 18:33:14 +02:00

Is there a built-in way to get the timezone difference formatted without : ? (without manually stripping the :. Don't know if there are any complications, if I do so)

Comment: Good question (+1).  What I want to know too.  I need to know which timezone the date is in.  We have a system in Java that has many Date fudges in it - but I always hoped something would be built into the .net framework to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *seems* (I've searched),  there's no way apart manipulating the resulting string. If you use `zz` you get only "+02" however... then you could append 00, instead of "searching"(regex or whatever) for the last : and strip it. `DateTimeFormatInfo` allows to know the separator for h:m:s, d/m/y, but not timezone; moreover if DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator affects timezone too (being h:m), you can't search for : snce it could not work on all locales, you should search for DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator instead; or zz and append 00 at the end... For now, it is all about my ideas to help you.

Comment: it could be (it is http://www.worldtimezone.com/wtz014.php )... but zz returns only the +04. It depends on how much important is to retain the correct exact timezone. If correct precise timing is needed, strip :, otherwise an error of +/-30 minutes is acceptable

Answer (score 3):

Note you can use "o" to have a full datetime with time zone. It can be usefull for log stuff.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o") => 2012-08-17T17:31:19.7538909+08:00
```